# How does IdP know if SP supports artifact messages?

Tags: saml, artifact

In SAML 2.0, IDP could choose to send artifact and have SP resolve. How does IdP know that SP supports artifact or not?

Answer (score 3):

Typically the IdP and SP exchange SAML metadata. This includes information about the supported SAML bindings and endpoint URLs. This occurs prior to any SSO and is part of the configuration process used to support SSO between the two parties.